# React / Redux conditionally applying style

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my `React & Redux` App, I am trying to `show/hide` a `div` based on `state` returned by `Redux`. Here is my code:

```
<div 
    className="notify-success" 
    style={{  ({this.props.terms}) ? "" : "display: 'none'" }} 
>
    Saved successfully!
</div>
```

But its not working for me, instead throwing an error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the condition on value, Use this:

```
style={{'display': this.props.terms ? "" : 'none' }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do not render the `<div>` if it is not needed:

```
render() {
    return { this.props.terms ?
             <div className="notify-success">
               Saved successfully!
             </div> : null 
           }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using classnames for better practice

```
  classNames('foo', 'bar'); // => 'foo bar'
  classNames('foo', { bar: true }); // => 'foo bar'
  classNames({ 'foo-bar': true }); // => 'foo-bar'
  classNames({ 'foo-bar': false }); // => ''
  classNames({ foo: true }, { bar: true }); // => 'foo bar'
  classNames({ foo: true, bar: true }); // => 'foo bar'
```

refer this link[classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames)

this will return you className generated you can put this in render method and as your variable changes this will get updated as you want.